# Deleting image opened from specific folder

Tags: android, image, delete-file

`visit https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwgJuKXMh_yGX1FPaENmQlVudWM`
    here I have uploaded my code and i want to delete the image that is opened in                          the full screen so please help me out.

Comment: try to write code here.. because no one will send you access request..

Comment: Your code is inaccessible. Either use github or post the relevant code here.

Comment: Have changed the editing setting

Comment: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BwgJuKXMh_yGX1FPaENmQlVudWM&usp=sharing

Comment: Share your code here.. no one going to see there.